# Looking for a Software to harden Windows machines

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, security, kiosk

I'm a network administrator of a small/medium network.

I'm looking for a software (Free or Not) which can harden Windows Computers (XP And Win7) for the propose of hardening standalone desktop computers (not in domain network).
Note: The computers are completely isolated (standalone), so i can't use active directory group policy. moreover, there are too many restriction that i need to apply, so it is not particle to set it up manual (one by one).
Basically what I’m looking for is a software that can restrict and disable access for specific user accounts on the system.

For Example:

1. User john can only open one application and nothing else -- He don’t see no icon on the desktop or start menu, except for one or two applications which i want to allow. He can't Right click on the desktop, the task-bar icons are not shown, there is no folder options, etc...
2. User marry can open a specific application and copy data to one folder on D drive.
3. User Dan, have access to all drives but cannot install software, and so on...

So far ,I've found only the following solutions, but they all seems to miss one or more feature:
Desktop restriction Software 
1. Faronics WINSelect The application seems to answer most of our needs except one feature  which is very important to us but seems to be missing from WINSelect, which is "restriction per profile". WINSelect  only allow to set up restrictions which are applied system-wide. If I have multiple user accounts on the system and want to apply different  restrictions for each user, I cant.

2. Deskman (No Restriction per user)-> Same thing, no restriction per profile.
3. Desktop Security Rx -> not relevant, No Win7 Support.
4. The only software that I've found which is offering a restriction per profile is " 1st Security Agent ". but its GUI is very complicated and not very intuitive.

It's worth to mention that I'm not looking for "Internet Kiosk software" although they share some features with the one I need. All I need is a software (like http://www.faronics.com/standard/winselect/) that is offering a way to restrict Windows user interface.

So IF anybody know an Hardening software which allows to set-up user restrictions on Windows systems, It will be a big, big, big help for me!

Thanks to you all

Comment: http://www.tricerat.com/products/tke So easy to use and their support is top notch, if you have any problems they will figure it out..

Comment: Hey,
The TKE software have only 10 restriction that can applied to the System (I just downloaded and check it) which is not nearly Enough...

Thanks anyway

Comment: Really? are you sure that's not just the trial version? I have it running and have everything restricted on my kiosks except firefox, word, adobe reader.

Comment: Well, I"ve downloaded the trial version, Which is supposed to be the full product for 30 days. MMM... are you saying you got lots od user restriction options to configure? anywhy I"m not sure its the solution I need. 

Its very strange to me that its so hard to find software like that out there. I never had a problem finding any time of software, except in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still working on this one, have a look at [this question over on Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1992/485) - there is a range of different tools and sources discussed there, some of which may be appropriate for you.